# MikTeX Deployment for multiple users

Tags: pdftex, miktex, installing, best-practices, windows

We use mainly MikTeX/pdflatex 2.9.

I'm wondering if the deployment scheme we have here is really the best. The way we deploy is as follows:

1. Create a miktex 2.9 System with required packages for our needs - put this on a Network drive where all users can access it.
2. Users copy the global System to a "local" Network drive - meaning a drive/Directory with which only they have access.
3. Users who need additional packages, send a package request to me. I update the global system - in other words, back to step 1.

This works. However, now the IT Administrators are complaining that the duplicate MikTeX Systems are redundant and waste storage space (I thought "wasting storage space" was a complaint from the past . . . ).

Anyway, when I put MikTeX in a global area and compile various documents asyncronously, I get a performance hit (for our basic documents, single user - one document at a time configuration - ca. 1-10 seconds per document, multi-user/async/multiple doc run - ca. 40-60 seconds per document).

Can it be that MikTeX/pdflatex is not necessarily a multiuser program (and maybe was never intentioned as such?).

Or is there a multiuser configuration I'm not aware of? Documentation at the MikTeX Project indicates that users should get their own local copy of MikTeX - which I think is similar to our current deployment.

Can it be that MikTeX/pdflatex updates/accesses the registry? I just noticed that nothing in the TeX Systems is updated during a run, however the registry appears to get updated. Does MikTeX/pdflatex update the registry?

DebugView Shows the following during a run:

```
00000676    3.65671015  [9500] 608 [pdflatex.core]: creating new file mapping object "jprogramtestmiktexmiktex.2.9plocaltexmfmiktexdataletexmf.fndb"
```

After further testing: What is a file mapping object? Is this a Memory mapped file or simply a reference to a temporary readable diskfile? Could this cause a performance hit when I test "multiusers" by scheduling pdflatex multiple times from one session? Although I compile different *.tex files, they use the same system and then the same *.fndb file.

Comment: sty files do not update the registry, but executables can also be updated and will update the registry.  On my single user system I have noticed that the first time I run MikTeX takes much longer than all subsequent runs (per session).

Comment: @JohnKormylo - re:Performance gain after first run. I've noticed this too - perhaps this has something to do with file system caching data used during the pdflatex Startup sequence?